# visualizing edge data for networkx-generated graphviz .dot or GML files

Tags: python, graphviz, networkx, graph-visualization

I have generated a graph with networkx, and exported it as a .dot file for vizualization.

The .dot file looks ok, there are the nodes and the node attributes I've created, as well as the edge data (`via` below), everything in place.

My problem is how to vizualize this data on linux? I've tried with **gephi**, it looks like the most capable among them, but it doesn't detect the edge attributes (`via`).

**I need to be able to explore the data interactively.**

Here is a simplified dot file which shows the same behavior

```
strict digraph G {
"README.md";
"src/modules/books/email_bk_title.php" [created="[466]"];
"functions/mysql/tmp" [created="[23, 43]"];
"src/modules/login/login_check.php" [created="[198]"];
"src/post_process_loader.php" [created="[178]"];
"src/style.css";
"src/templates/default/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js" [created="[8]"];
"src/webroot/templates/default/js/bootstrap-modal.js" [created="[23]"];
"src/webroot/templates/default/js/bootstrap-transition.js" [created="[23]"];
"src/templates/default/js/bootstrap-collapse.js" [created="[8]"];
"src/modules/books/tmp";
"src/templates/default/css/bootstrap.css" [created="[8]"];
"LICENSE.txt" [created="[6]"];
"src/templates/default/js/bootstrap.js" [created="[8]"];
"docs/app_skel_design.md" [created="[39]"];
"src/webroot/templates/default/js/bootstrap-button.js" [created="[23]"];
"src/templates/default/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.css" [created="[8]"];
"src/templates/default/js/bootstrap-tab.js" [created="[8]"];
"src/modules/logout/logout_bl.php" [created="[280]"];
"functions/books/tmp" [created="[23, 43]"];
"src/modules/admin/tmp";
"src/modules/register/tmp" [created="[73, 94]"];
"docs/database/db_constraints_behavior.md" [created="[38]"];
"src/webroot/templates/default/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js" [created="[23]"];
"uploads/tmp" [created="[237]"];
"src/modules/login/login.php" [created="[127]"];
"src/resources/books/books.php" [created="[306, 366, 518]"];
"src/resource_holder.php" [created="[221, 250, 304, 428]"];
"src/modules/session/session_start.php" [created="[177]"];
"src/webroot/templates/default/index.html" [created="[23]"];
".gitignore" [created="[170, 289]"];
"src/functions/mysql/tmp" [created="[44]"];
"src/webroot/templates/default/js/bootstrap.js" [created="[23]"];
"src/modules/user/user_bl.php" [created="[142, 169, 439]"];
"src/modules/logout/logout.php" [created="[156, 270]"];
"src/webroot/templates/default/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js" [created="[23]"];
"src/modules/base/functions.php" [created="[64, 158, 232, 233, 254]"];
"src/resources/base/functions.php";
"docs/roadmap/v0.2.0-v0.4.0.txt" [created="[209]"];
"src/templates/default/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js" [created="[8]"];
"docs/database/mylibrary.sql" [created="[29]"];
"src/resource_holder.php.php" [created="[216]"];
"src/webroot/templates/default/js/bootstrap-popover.js" [created="[23]"];
"src/modules/register/register.php" [created="[93, 110, 455, 457]"];
"src/webroot/style.css" [created="[41, 46, 63, 126]"];
"src/webroot/templates/default/js/jquery.js" [created="[23]"];
"docs/install on windows.md" [created="[500, 501, 502, 503]"];
"src/webroot/templates/default/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.css" [created="[23]"];
"src/templates/default/js/bootstrap-alert.js" [created="[8]"];
"src/modules/books/books_bl.php" [created="[125, 514]"];
"src/webroot/module_holder.php" [created="[51, 89]"];
"src/webroot/templates/default/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js" [created="[23]"];
"src/templates/default/js/README.md" [created="[8]"];
"src/webroot/templates/default/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js" [created="[23]"];
"src/resources/register/register_BL.php" [created="[243]"];
"src/webroot/index.php" [created="[41, 52, 113, 136, 181]"];
"docs/wireframe/my-library.ep" [created="[7]"];
"webroot/uploads/tmp";
"src/functions/base/functions.php" [created="[48]"];
"src/webroot/templates/default/js/bootstrap.min.js" [created="[23]"];
"src/functions/admin/tmp" [created="[44]"];
"src/templates/default/js/bootstrap-carousel.js" [created="[8]"];
"src/modules/recover/tmp" [created="[72, 535]"];
"src/modules/register/content.php" [created="[92, 111]"];
"docs/roadmap/roadmap.md";
"src/resources/authentication/authentication.php" [created="[255, 277, 382, 449, 460, 462]"];
"src/webroot/templates/default/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" [created="[23]"];
"src/resources/admin/admin.php" [created="[403, 414, 419, 484, 487]"];
"src/webroot/templates/default/js/bootstrap-carousel.js" [created="[23]"];
"src/webroot/templates/default/js/bootstrap-collapse.js" [created="[23]"];
"src/modules/books/books.php" [created="[117, 440]"];
"src/functions/user/tmp" [created="[44]"];
"functions/user/tmp" [created="[23, 43]"];
"src/templates/default/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js" [created="[8]"];
"webroot/style.css";
"src/modules/admin/admin.php" [created="[296, 303, 383, 397, 412, 421, 473, 491]"];
"functions/admin/tmp" [created="[23, 43]"];
"src/webroot/templates/default/js/bootstrap-alert.js" [created="[23]"];
"src/webroot/templates/default/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.js" [created="[23]"];
"src/functions/books/tmp" [created="[44]"];
"src/templates/default/js/bootstrap.min.js" [created="[8]"];
"src/webroot/layout.php" [created="[41, 45, 84]"];
"src/modules/admin/admin_bl.php" [created="[297, 369, 398, 438, 493]"];
"src/webroot/templates/default/css/docs.css" [created="[23]"];
"src/modules/user/tmp";
"src/modules/mysql/tmp";
"src/modules/mysql/connect.php" [created="[91]"];
"src/resources/upload/upload.php" [created="[290, 389]"];
"src/dependency_loader.php" [created="[95]"];
"docs/structure.md" [created="[16, 49]"];
"src/templates/default/js/bootstrap-button.js" [created="[8]"];
"config/mysql_credentials.php-dist" [created="[170]"];
"src/webroot/templates/default/js/README.md" [created="[23]"];
"src/templates/default/js/bootstrap-modal.js" [created="[8]"];
"src/templates/default/index.html" [created="[8]"];
"src/templates/default/js/bootstrap-popover.js" [created="[8]"];
"docs/roadmap/roadmap_gantt.gan" [created="[18]"];
"src/resources/autologin/autologin.php" [created="[241]"];
"src/templates/default/js/bootstrap-transition.js" [created="[8]"];
"src/resources/mysql/mysql.php";
"src/modules/mysql/mysql.php" [created="[82]"];
"src/resources_loader.php" [created="[214]"];
"src/modules/home/home.php" [created="[64]"];
"webroot/index.php";
"src/modules/user/user.php" [created="[141, 164]"];
"README.MD" [created="[0, 1]"];
"src/templates/default/css/docs.css" [created="[8]"];
"docs/features.md" [created="[4]"];
"src/modules/upload/upload_bl.php" [created="[236]"];
"src/templates/default/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" [created="[8]"];
"src/webroot/templates/default/js/application.js" [created="[23]"];
"src/layout.php";
"src/templates/default/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.js" [created="[8]"];
"src/modules/login/login_BL.php" [created="[146]"];
"src/empty" [created="[5, 8]"];
"src/resources/user/user.php" [created="[426, 434, 522]"];
"src/resources/session/session_start.php";
"src/modules/register/validation_mail_content.php" [created="[480]"];
"src/resources/login/login_bl.php" [created="[242]"];
"src/modules/login/login_bl.php";
"src/modules/session/session_destroy.php" [created="[177, 186]"];
"src/pre_process_loader.php" [created="[179]"];
"src/router.php" [created="[78]"];
"src/resources/session/session_destroy.php";
"src/modules/login/tmp" [created="[71, 124]"];
"src/moduleBL_loader.php" [created="[112]"];
"src/webroot/templates/default/js/bootstrap-tab.js" [created="[23]"];
"src/modules/register/register_BL.php" [created="[121, 448]"];
"src/templates/default/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js" [created="[8]"];
"src/module_holder.php";
"src/webroot/templates/default/css/bootstrap.css" [created="[23]"];
"src/modules/upload/upload.php" [created="[235]"];
"src/templates/default/js/jquery.js" [created="[8]"];
"src/templates/default/js/application.js" [created="[8]"];
"todo.txt" [created="[31]"];
"src/style.css" -> "src/webroot/style.css"  [via=99];
"uploads/tmp" -> "webroot/uploads/tmp"  [via=394];
"src/modules/session/session_start.php" -> "src/resources/session/session_start.php"  [via=212];
"src/functions/mysql/tmp" -> "src/modules/mysql/tmp"  [via=64];
"src/modules/base/functions.php" -> "src/resources/base/functions.php"  [via=257];
"docs/roadmap/v0.2.0-v0.4.0.txt" -> "docs/roadmap/roadmap.md"  [via=227];
"src/webroot/style.css" -> "src/style.css"  [via=86];
"src/webroot/style.css" -> "webroot/style.css"  [via=172];
"src/webroot/module_holder.php" -> "src/module_holder.php"  [via=86];
"src/resources/register/register_BL.php" -> "src/modules/register/register_BL.php"  [via=256];
"src/webroot/index.php" -> "webroot/index.php"  [via=172];
"src/functions/admin/tmp" -> "src/modules/admin/tmp"  [via=64];
"src/functions/user/tmp" -> "src/modules/user/tmp"  [via=64];
"src/functions/books/tmp" -> "src/modules/books/tmp"  [via=64];
"src/webroot/layout.php" -> "src/layout.php"  [via=86];
"src/modules/mysql/mysql.php" -> "src/resources/mysql/mysql.php"  [via=211];
"README.MD" -> "README.md"  [via=3];
"src/modules/login/login_BL.php" -> "src/modules/login/login_bl.php"  [via=173];
"src/resources/login/login_bl.php" -> "src/modules/login/login_bl.php"  [via=256];
"src/modules/session/session_destroy.php" -> "src/resources/session/session_destroy.php"  [via=212];
}
```

In networkx, I create it like this

```
filegraph = nx.DiGraph()

for cid, commit in enumerate(raw.commits):
    raw_creations = [info['path'] for info in raw.commits[cid]['info'] if info['type'] & RawRepo.TYPE_NEW]
    for path in raw_creations:
        if path in filegraph:
            attrs = filegraph.node[path]
            if 'created' in attrs:
                attrs['created'].append(cid)
            else:
                print("not in created")
        else:
            print("created", path)
            attrs = {'created': [cid]}
        filegraph.add_node(path, attr_dict=attrs)
    raw_renames = {info['from']:info['to'] for info in raw.commits[cid]['info'] if info['type'] & RawRepo.TYPE_RENAME}
    for fr, to in raw_renames.items():
        print("rename",fr,"->",to)
        filegraph.add_edge(fr, to)
        filegraph.edge[fr][to]['via'] = cid
        #filegraph.add_edge(fr, to, attr_dict={'via':cid})

nx.drawing.nx_pydot.write_dot(filegraph, 'filenames.dot')
```

The other viewer I've tried, **ZGRViewer**, doesn't show that data either.

## Update

With cytoscape 3.0.0-beta1 it gives this error, and a similar error with cytoscape 2.8.3, when importing a GML file exported with networkx as

```
nx.readwrite.gml.write_gml(filegraph, 'filenames.gml')
```

The error is

```
java.text.ParseException: Bad value associated with key modified
        at org.cytoscape.io.internal.read.gml.GMLParser.parseList(GMLParser.java:192)
        at org.cytoscape.io.internal.read.gml.GMLParser.parseValue(GMLParser.java:293)
        at org.cytoscape.io.internal.read.gml.GMLParser.parseList(GMLParser.java:189)
        at org.cytoscape.io.internal.read.gml.GMLParser.parseValue(GMLParser.java:293)
        at org.cytoscape.io.internal.read.gml.GMLParser.parseList(GMLParser.java:189)
        at org.cytoscape.io.internal.read.gml.GMLNetworkReader.run(GMLNetworkReader.java:190)
        at org.cytoscape.work.internal.task.JDialogTaskManager$TaskThread.run(JDialogTaskManager.java:241)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
pool-11-thread-1 WARN [org.cytoscape.work.internal.task.JDialogTaskManager] - Caught exception executing task.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad value associated with key modified
        at org.cytoscape.io.internal.read.gml.GMLNetworkReader.run(GMLNetworkReader.java:193)
        at org.cytoscape.work.internal.task.JDialogTaskManager$TaskThread.run(JDialogTaskManager.java:241)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

The Error in cytoscape 2.8.3 looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For interactive network visualization, manipulation, and analysis, I strongly recommend [Cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/).  It supports edge attributes, has a great UI, and active development community. However, it *cannot* import .dot files, so if you want to use Cytoscape, you'll need to go back to NetworkX and export as GML, which is easily done from NetworkX.

I should also say that although I haven't used Gephi, it sounded odd to me that it doesn't support edge attributes, and it turns out that it does support edge attributes. You can get some basic insight into this [here.](http://forum.gephi.org/viewtopic.php?t=1792)

Comment: It does not import edge attributes from .dot. Except for label.

Comment: Is there a reason your export needs to be in .dot format as opposed to GML?  NetworkX also supports GML exports (see [here](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/readwrite.gml.html) in documentation), which you can work with across a variety of network visualization programs such as Gephi and Cytoscape.

Comment: When I try to import the gml file, it gives a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. And I've tried with cytoscape and gml ... please see my update

Comment: Ugg -- pygraphviz is giving me guff, so I can't try to replicate your process.  This actually got me thinking though, do you even need networkX?  Are you using nx for anything beside putting the data into graph format?  If so, I think you're further ahead just transforming your raw data directly into an edge list and accompanying attribute table, and cutting out networkx completely.   Can you give an example of what your raw data looks like before you put into a graph via nx?

Comment: Another thought -- I wonder if it might be the case that your node IDs are causing problems, possibly because of encoding issues or an escape character somewhere in a node id.  In general, it's good practice to give your nodes a more standardized entity for the ID, and then you can provide the full name (e.g., "src/modules/books/email_bk_title.php") as a node attribute, in the same way you did for the "created" attribute.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21831/discussion-between-benjamin-white-and-flavius)

Answer (score -1):

I am using "render" from graphvis.

```
from graphviz import render
```

with the next function

```
nx.drawing.nx_pydot.write_dot(self, filename)
render(engine='dot', format=output_format, filepath=filename)
```

(the file name is the dot file and the output_format is 'svg' or other good format that can be parsed by regular applicaton). I ususaly use firefox to open the generated svg file.